# Calc of timedelta between IN and OUT events after midnight

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

The below is the code for sandbox, - original obviously quite larger...

the main problem is, -
I cannot figure out how to calc timedelta if LogOut was done after midnight, - however, the event should be treated as if it happened a day before...

**Example**, Log In was @ 2**2**/03/2022 18:00:00, Log Out was @ 2**3**/03/2022 01:00:00
The result should show time delta 7 hours, the Log Day - Tuesday, Date - 22/03/2022.

At the moment, I am thinking to create new Date column and offset 4 hours in it `df['NewDate'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['LogDateTime']) - timedelta(hours=4)).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` later split and merge using new Date, but I am not sure if it is the bes way to move forward...

Any ideas or directions would be very helpful...
(thanks in advance)

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[515, '2022-03-16 17:01:11',    'In', 'Wed', '16/03/2022'],
        [515, '2022-03-17 00:16:36',    'Out', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [515, '2022-03-17 00:16:49',    'Out', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [515, '2022-03-17 16:42:40',    'In', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [515, '2022-03-17 23:48:09',    'Out', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [333, '2022-03-17 17:16:36',    'In', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [333, '2022-03-17 17:16:45',    'In', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [333, '2022-03-17 17:16:51',    'In', 'Thu', '17/03/2022'],
        [333, '2022-03-17 22:55:03',    'Out', 'Thu', '17/03/2022']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'LogDateTime', 'EventType', 'Log Day', 'Date'])
df.LogDateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.LogDateTime)
df.dtypes

df = df.sort_values(by=['LogDateTime', 'ID'])

dfIn = df.loc[(df.EventType == "In")]
dfOut = df.loc[(df.EventType == "Out")]

# dfIn = dfIn.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Date', 'Log Day'], keep='first') # Cannot be used due to midnight issue...
# dfOut = dfIn.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Date', 'Log Day'], keep='first') # Cannot be used due to midnight issue...

FinDF = pd.merge(dfIn, dfOut, on=['ID', 'Log Day', 'Date'], how='left')
FinDF.rename(columns={'LogDateTime_x': 'Log In', 'LogDateTime_y': 'Log Out'}, inplace=True)

FinDF['Hours'] = round((FinDF['Log Out'] - FinDF['Log In']).astype('timedelta64[m]') / 60, 2)
FinDF.to_excel(r'C:\Test\test.xlsx', index=False)
```

As per example above, data has quite a lot duplicated events, I tried to use max values in Out events and oposite in In events, - however due to midnight issue, - I loose data..

The end result should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you merge your DataFrames, you will have to keep only one the first "In" and last "Out" when there are consecutive occurrences. You can then continue on with your existing logic of merging the two dataframes and finding the time difference.

Try:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','LogDateTime'])

groups = ((df["ID"].eq(df["ID"].shift())&df["EventType"].ne(df["EventType"].shift()))|(df["ID"].ne(df["ID"].shift()))).cumsum()

#minimum timestamp to be used for EventType = "In"
mins = df.groupby(groups)["LogDateTime"].transform("min")

#maximum timestamp to be used for EventType = "In"
maxs = df.groupby(groups)["LogDateTime"].transform("max")

condensed = df[df["LogDateTime"].eq(mins.where(df["EventType"].eq("In"), maxs))].reset_index(drop=True)
condensed["Group"] = condensed.index//2

FinDF = condensed[condensed["EventType"].eq("In")].merge(condensed.loc[condensed["EventType"].eq("Out"), ["LogDateTime", "Group"]], on="Group").drop(["EventType", "Group"], axis=1)
FinDF = FinDF.rename(columns={'LogDateTime_x': 'Log In', 'LogDateTime_y': 'Log Out'})
FinDF['Hours'] = FinDF["Log Out"].sub(FinDF["Log In"]).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).round(2)

>>> FinDF
    ID              Log In Log Day        Date             Log Out  Hours
0  333 2022-03-17 17:16:36     Thu  17/03/2022 2022-03-17 22:55:03   5.64
1  515 2022-03-16 17:01:11     Wed  16/03/2022 2022-03-17 00:16:49   7.26
2  515 2022-03-17 16:42:40     Thu  17/03/2022 2022-03-17 23:48:09   7.09
```

Comment: Very nice and interesting approach, - lots of to read and learn.
However, in my case, after `FinDF = condensed[condensed["EventType"].eq ...`, all entries are lost except one row , - FinDF result ends up as  `0  515 2022-03-16 17:01:11     Wed  16/03/2022 2022-03-17 00:16:49   7.26` ...
"condensed" looks OK, it has all entries + column "Group".
My Python ver3.9

Comment: found it... 
the strange behavior I described above, takes place if I keep the sorting code `df = df.sort_values(by=['LogDateTime', 'ID'])` before yours takes the place...
I do not get the idea yet, as not completely sure how yours does the trick

Comment: Hmm. Try change your sorting to `df.sort_values(by=['ID','LogDateTime'])` (first by ID and then all the times for that ID).

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late. I found your grouping approach extremely nice, however, I am not able to solve the problem, if ID has one LogIn or LogOut missing during a shift...